# produce a non deterministic result for each tibble row with mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

```
tibble(x=c(1,2,3)) %>%
  mutate(y = runif(1))
```

This results in the same quantity assigned to each Y.  Why is this and how can i ensure the function I supply is called once for each row, regardless of the value and type of the arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `n` argument of `runif()` takes either an integer or a vector of values.  If a vector is used its length is taken to be the number required.  This means you can pass it a vector of any class and it will return a result of equal length.

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(x=c(1,2,3)) %>%
  mutate(y = runif(x))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 0.445
2     2 0.778
3     3 0.632
```

Comment: Thanks.  Runif was used just for purpose of example.  Is it a general rule when implementing a function in R to allow the argument to be scalar or vector, so it can be used in this context.  In my use case my function did not take any arguments and returned a random date.

Comment: rndDate <- function() {
  toString(sample(seq(as.Date('2019/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 1))
}

tibble(x=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(x==TRUE, rndDate(),NA))

Comment: This isn't related to `runif()` but rather how `ifelse()` functions.  It doesn't execute each time the condition is true but only once.  So you need to ensure that the `TRUE` and `FALSE` return values are of equal length to the `test`, otherwise a single value is recycled.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't quite understand how to ensure the return values are of equal length.  But following the pattern I got it to work with this slightly unsightly code.

rndDateScalar <- function(x = TRUE) { 
  ifelse(x,
    toString(sample(seq(as.Date('2019/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 1)) ,
    NA)
} ; 


rndDate <- Vectorize(rndDateScalar);


tibble(x=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% mutate(y = rndDate(x))

Comment: Try: `rndDate <- function(x) {
  sample(seq(as.Date('2019/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), x)
  }; tibble(x=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(y = if_else(x, rndDate(length(x)), as.Date(NA)))`